# Why can't I use subtypes from limited withed packages in subprogram declarations?

Tags: ada

In Ada 2012, a limited with can be used from one file (for example, User) to import types from another package (for example, Provider), even when that package needs to import the current file. This is useful in cases where you have two mutually dependent types, such as the following, but you have them in two different packages, so you can't just use an incomplete type declaration like this:

```
    type Point;
    type Line;    -- incomplete types

    type Point is
        record
            L, M, N: access Line;
    end record;

    type Line is
        record
            P, Q, R: access Point;
    end record;
```

(the above example is from [John Barnes' Programming in Ada 2012](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/programming-in-ada-2012-with-a-preview-of-ada-2022/AD30275F35CCECB97EAB80ABC32B019C), section 13.5 Mutually dependent types)

However, my question doesn't even need mutually dependent types. I'm trying to compile some Ada code that was autogenerated using `gcc -fdump-ada-spec -C some_c_header.h`, which happens to contain some procedures and/or functions that have parameters being passed as `access constant` (`const *` in C), and I see no reason this shouldn't work using `limited with`, as fdump-ada-spec generates for me.

Why can't I use any subtypes from Provider inside a subprogram declaration? Using regular types is fine, but when trying to use subtypes gcc complains they do not exist in that package.

#### provider.ads

```
package Provider is

   type Fine_Type is range 0 .. 10_000;
   subtype Bad_Type is Fine_Type;

end Provider;
```

#### user.ads:

```
limited with Provider;

package User is

   procedure Do_It (A : access constant Provider.Bad_Type);

end User;
```

For completeness, here are stubs for the rest of the files you would need:

#### user.adb

```
package body User is

   procedure Do_It (A : access constant Provider.Bad_Type) is
   begin
      null;
   end Do_It;

end User;
```

#### limited_with_test.gpr

```
project limited_with_test is

   for Source_Dirs use ("src");
   for Main use ("main.adb");

   for Exec_Dir use "bin";
   for Object_Dir use "obj";
   for Create_Missing_Dirs use "True";

end limited_with_test;
```

If you put the sources into a directory called src, you can call gprbuild in the directory containing that directory and the gpr file, and you get:

```
$ gprbuild
using project file limited_with_test.gpr
Compile
   [Ada]          main.adb
user.ads:5:49: error: "Bad_Type" not declared in "Provider"
gprbuild: *** compilation phase failed
```

Answer (score 3):

An Ada subtype is not a new type. A subtype is a member of its parent type with possibly some value restrictions. Limited with gives visibility to types and not subtypes. The only type declared in provider is Fine_Type. If you want visibility to Bad_Type you must use a non-limited with.

```ada
with provider;
```

Comment: So, does that mean `gcc -fdump-ada-spec` is implemented incorrectly?

Comment: It could be so.